# AKS attach-acr error after migrating from one subscription to another

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-container-registry

I just migrated from one subscription to another on Azure. Although the `subscriptionId` is the same, the `tenantId` was changed.

After the migration, my AKS cluster no longer can pull images from the ACR. My AKS currently uses service principles that I believe are no longer valid after the migration. I have updated the service principle but I'm still not able to pull the image.

Is there any other configuration that I need to be aware of?

Answer (score 1):

Pls verify if the Role "AcrPull" is still assigned to the Managed Identity (Kubelet) of the AKS node pool.

Terrafrom example:

```
  resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example" {
    scope                            = azurerm_container_registry.acr.id
    role_definition_name             = "AcrPull"
    principal_id                     = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kubelet_identity[0].object_id
  }
```

AZ cli example:

```
export KUBE_ID=$(az aks show -g <resource group> -n <aks cluster name> --query identityProfile.kubeletidentity.objectId -o tsv)
export ACR_ID=$(az acr show -g <resource group> -n <acr name> --query id -o tsv)
az role assignment create --assignee $KUBE_ID --role "AcrPull" --scope $ACR_ID
```

Comment: My KUBE_ID is empty. Does that I mean I should be creating a new az role? I checked the AKS and the my IdentityProfile is null since I'm using SP

Comment: Then try this pls (for KUBE_ID) : --query identity.principalId

Comment: You could also attach your ACR to the AKS -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-container-registry-integration?tabs=azure-cli&WT.mc_id=twitter

Comment: Actually just realized I was trying on the wrong cluster. I tried the Az CLI commands, and I get the following error "Cannot find user or service principal in graph database for 'xxx-xxxx-xxx'. If the assignee is an appId, make sure the corresponding service principal is created with 'az ad sp create --id xxx-xxxx-xxx'"

Comment: I get this error when I try to attach the ACR "Could not create a role assignment for ACR. Are you an Owner on this subscription?" I am the Global administrator of the subscription

Comment: What is the output from -> az aks show -g <RGName> -n <ClusterName> --query "identity"

Comment: {
  "principalId": "xxxxxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxx",
  "tenantId": "xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx",
  "type": "SystemAssigned",
  "userAssignedIdentities": null
}

Comment: Normally you should be able to assign the principal ID to the AcrPull Role. Did you also mirgrated the ACR to the new Tenannt ?

Comment: Yes, I migrated all of my resources from one subscription to another. All of the resources are in the new tenant now

Comment: I am not sure but do I need to create a new identity?

Comment: Can you check https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/15188 & https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/7629

Comment: you could update the aks and add a managed identity -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-managed-identity?WT.mc_id=twitter